# Не подключается Fontawesome в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fontawesome

Есть такая структура папок:

[image: структура папок]

Прописал в файле function.php:

[image: код в файле function.php]

В браузере видно, что fontawesome подключился:

[image: код в браузере]

Однако в итоге иконки не отображаются:

[image: итог]

В файле font-awesome.min.css прописаны следующие пути к файлам:

[image: код в файле font-awesome.min.css]

Что я сделал не так?

В консоле:

[image: консоль]

HTML код:

[image: HTML-код вывода иконок]

Comment: какие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: В консоле ошибок связанных с fontawesome нет. Первая и третья, я так понимаю из-за того, что я пути ещё не указывал к этим картинкам. А почему на RobotoRegular ругается мне также не понятно.

Comment: А как вы выводите иконки? Какой html-код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас неправильно описаны иконки в html-коде. Например, facebook описывается так в FontAwesome 4.7.0

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

[Документация](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/facebook/).

Comment: Да, действительно в статической вёрстке оказались файлы двух версий FontAwesome... и 4-ой и 5-ой. А при переносе на Wordpress добавлял не ту версию FontAwesome. Спасибо за помощь!!!

Answer (score 0):

Судя по Консоли у вас неверный регистр в именах файлов. Сделайте всё маленькими буквами (при загрузке через ftp).